# Django ORM Confusion with Query

Tags: django, django-orm

I have `customer` Model

```
Name, Email, Phone, State
```

### example

```
A, Aemail, Apohone, Astate
A, Bemail, Apohone, Astate
A, Cemail, Apohone, Astate
```

Means one customer with multiple emails.
Here what i want to get out of the query.

```
[{A, Aphone, Astate, [Aemail, Bemail, Cemail]},
{....},
]
```

### Tried

```
Customers.objects.filter(**params).values_list('phone', 'name').distinct()
```

Thougts?

Answer (score 1):

The schema you describe is sub-optimal. Using this schema will result in consistency issues when only some of the user's data will be updated/deleted.

If you want the `Customer` to have multiple `email`s if would be wiser to create a separate `Email` model or use array field.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CustomerEmail(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='emails')
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Now it becomes easy make the query you want.

```
customers = Customer.objects.select_related('emails')
```

And get their emails:

```
for email in customers.emails:
    print(email.email)
```

Comment: I agree; But this table has bulk of data, imported from CSV. Can you help me with the query, i totally agree with the schema change you described. Any solution with the query?